# Angular 4 display images

Tags: html, angular, image, typescript

I am trying to add an image with angular 4 ... but without success

My folders :

src

```
- app
    - job
        job.component.css
        job.component.html
        job.component.specs.ts
        job.component.ts

- assets
    - images
        play-3.png

favicon.ico
```

What I have tried :

```
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="../assets/images/play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="../../assets/images/play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="../../../assets/images/play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="/assets/images/play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="./assets/images/play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="/assets/images/play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="assets/images/play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="./assets/images/play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="assets\images\play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="images/play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="favicon.ico"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="./play-3.png"/></a>
 <a href="ta_page" ><img src="app/assets/images/play-3.png"/></a>              
 <img ng-src="assets/images/play-3.png">
 <img ng-src="images/play-3.png">
```

error :

```
Cannot GET /play-3.png
```

If I put favicon it works ....

I tried to put my images into /src, src/assets, src/assets/images ...

Edit :

my .angular-cli.json

```
  "apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
```

Solution :
- Restart ng serve after pgn upload

Comment: src="assets/images/play-3.png" this one is may be working properly. You try this buggy wayin you img tag

Comment: new try, <img src="assets/images/play-3.png"> not working , error : <pre>Cannot GET /assets/images/play-3.png</pre>

Comment: have you give any with height value for that img

Comment: For reference my .angular-cli.json file has:

"assets": [
        "assets",
        "play-3.png"
      ],

Comment: I tryied with 3 differents images and size (32x32 like favicon etc)
(if i put for example https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg it works)

Comment: not working with angular-cli modification

Comment: according to base tag specification

The base URL to be used throughout the document for relative URL addresses. If this attribute is specified, this element must come before any other elements with attributes whose values are URLs. Absolute and relative URLs are allowed.

Comment: in angular-cli projects the base href is "/" (.html)
so all paths, including urls in css, and including relative and absolute paths, should have / appended to them. Instead, relative paths have './'

The solution of manually adding '/' for absolute paths is not good enough, since different server environments on different builds might differ in the wanted 'base' url.

I assume it's a loader issue. Not sure how it plays with the rest of the configuration, but raw-loader follows this spec perfectly.

Comment: Did you restart ng serve after adding the png image?

Comment: no i didn't restart ng serve, i checked out my code on another computer, the first 9 lines work !!! Maybe ng serve must be restarted to work, i will test on Tuesday with the main computer.... Thanks

Comment: it works after the first launch ... maybe I should have to restart ng serve ..

Answer (score 2):

In angular-cli.json you should have this:

```
> "apps": [
>     {
>       "root": "src",
>       "outDir": "dist",
>       "assets": [
>         "assets",
>         "favicon.ico"
>       ]
```

assets is the folder to static files, ok,now you have to put the images in a folder into assets /src/assets/images/play-3.png, finally you can access to image, from you app.component.html, with:

```
<img src="/images/play-3.png"/></a>
```

Comment: I pub my angular-cli, i have the same things, new try same error

Answer (score 0):

with your folder structure src/assets/images where your images are in the images folder, this should work:

- 

As long as you have this declaration in your angular-cli.json

> "apps": [
>       {
>         "root": "src",
>         "outDir": "dist",
>         "assets": [
>           "assets",
>           "favicon.ico"
>         ]